# Upon load Magento shows logo twice and after few ms it display properly

Tags: magento-1.9

This Magento store is live from July it has this strange issue, upon load it shows logo twice on almost all pages and after a ms it displays properly. I am not able to understand how to describe it more effectively, so this images here for [image: chrome], [image: safari] and [image: firefox]. It is more visible on chrome.

Comment: I'm not a css wizard, but i think it'll be a delay in your CSS loading. The logo will probably be styled to render twice and then extra CSS loads in that causes the error to disappear. That is consistent with seeing the menu etc loading as a bullet list down the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with your theme.

[image]

The logo is on the page twice, with both image instances right next to each other, and one instance set to `display: none`. There is likely a piece of JavaScript or CSS that is designed to select one image over the other for display, likely for responsiveness*.

This should give you some pointers on starting to fix the issue by identifying the problem at a deeper level than just "the logo shows up twice". If I were in your place, I'd start by digging into the theme to see why the logo shows up twice, and then making a decision about whether to output it twice** or just once. If you end up having to display it twice, in your `template.phtml` file, set the tag that you don't want to start with to `display: none;` inline, so you don't have to wait for the CSS to load

*This is a phenomeonally poor way to develop a responsive theme. It makes the browser download and render the image twice (reducing page speed), and leads to issues like this. Just outputting it once and then resizing it is much better.

**See my above comment - please don't do this.

Points to @LukeRodgers for pointing out the likely CSS issue.

Comment: I implemented the change you suggested but still the problem reproduces.